# Editing data in rows

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert my data in R, but I can't manage to get the column I want.

My dataset is as below, and the column I want to get is "total", it is the sum of D1 + D2 + D3 + D4 + D5, and ignores "NA".

| NR | D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | D5 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | NA | NA | 1 | NA | 2 |
| B | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| C | NA | 1 | NA | NA | NA | 1 |

It is probably quite a domb question, but I can't get it.

I already tried:

```
total <- NA 
total <- ifelse(D1==1, 1, total) 
total <- ifelse(D2==1, total + 1, total) 
total <- ifelse(D3==1, total + 1, total) 
total <- ifelse(D4==1, total + 1, total) 
total <- ifelse(D5==1, total + 1, total)
```

But it returns all my rows to "NA"

and i tried:

```
total <- mutate(dataset, total=D1+D2+D3+D4+D5)
```

but then I don't get an aggregation of the values of D1 to D5.

Answer (score 5):

We could use `rowSums`

```
df1$total <- rowSums(df1[startsWith(names(df1), "D")], na.rm = TRUE)
df1$total[df1$total == 0] <- NA
```

---

Or the same logic in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(total = na_if(rowSums(select(., starts_with('D')), na.rm = TRUE), 0))
  NR D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 total
1  A  1 NA NA  1 NA     2
2  B NA NA NA NA NA    NA
3  C NA  1 NA NA NA     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(NR = c("A", "B", "C"), D1 = c(1L, NA, NA), D2 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L), D3 = c(NA, NA, NA), D4 = c(1L, NA, NA), D5 = c(NA, NA, 
NA), total = c(2L, NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use `select(., ...)` instead of `across(...)` here?

Comment: @GuedesBF With `across`, we are looping across those columns and applying some function individually on those columns, Here, with `rowSums`, we want to get all those columns together i.e. the reason I used `select`

Comment: @GuedesBF you may use `c_across` + `rowwise` as well, but that would be less efficient

Comment: Ok, thanks I usually think like this. But i am surprised to see across actually works, as in :
`identical(iris%>%mutate(total=rowSums(across(starts_with("Se")))), iris%>%mutate(total=rowSums(select(., starts_with("Se")))))
[1] TRUE`.

That could be in a a new question. Thanks as always, @akrun.

Comment: @GuedesBF, but here, you are not applying any function inside `across`, it is just used as a means to select those columns which the `select` does anyway.  I don't know whether there would be any efficiency involved.  I suspect there could be because `across` could have more checks inside as it involves computation as well

Comment: I think the only advantage of across would be to omit the `.` argument, but that is hardly an advantage.

Comment: @GuedesBF it would be a good exercise to try with `microbenchmark` on a big dataset with both `across` and `select` on `rowSums`

Comment: I benchmarked with an 1e7 row df, and both methods are pretty much the same. thanks

Comment: @GuedesBF thanks. still I may use `select`, as it will automatically make the code more understandable compared to `across`.  For me, `across` code would give an indication that some function is applied individually on those columns

Comment: I used this one! Thanks, it is fixed now!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution with `c_across` and `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
  df %>%
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(Total = sum(c_across(D1:D5 & where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Output:

```
  NR       D1    D2 D3       D4 D5    Total
  <chr> <int> <int> <lgl> <int> <lgl> <int>
1 A         1    NA NA        1 NA        2
2 B        NA    NA NA       NA NA        0
3 C        NA     1 NA       NA NA        1
```

data:

```
structure(list(NR = c("A", "B", "C"), D1 = c(1L, NA, NA), D2 = c(NA, 
NA, 1L), D3 = c(NA, NA, NA), D4 = c(1L, NA, NA), D5 = c(NA, NA, 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try the code below

```
df$total <- replace(u <- rowSums(!is.na(df)) - 1, u == 0, NA)
```

which gives

```
> df
  NR D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 total
1  A  1 NA NA  1 NA     2
2  B NA NA NA NA NA    NA
3  C NA  1 NA NA NA     1
```

Answer (score 2):

And also this one:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df1 <- df1[, !names(df1) %in% "total"] 
df1 %>%
  mutate(total = pmap_dbl(select(cur_data(), starts_with("D")), ~ ifelse(all(is.na(c(...))), 
                                                                          NA, sum(c(...), na.rm = TRUE))))

  NR D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 total
1  A  1 NA NA  1 NA     2
2  B NA NA NA NA NA    NA
3  C NA  1 NA NA NA     1
```